# Linked List prgrm stopped working error

Tags: c, linked-list, crash

I am writing a linked list program in C

The problem is with create function. 
Create() works perfectly at the first run. Then when i exit to menu and call the create function again the program crashes with the message "linkedlist has stopped working" Hint: linkedlist is the name of my prgrm.

```
void create()
{
    do
   {
       printf("Enter the num:");
       head=(NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
       scanf("%d",&head->num);
       head->next=NULL;
       if(start==NULL)
           start=ptr=head;
       else
       {
           ptr->next=head;
           ptr=head;
       }
       printf("Do you want to enter more elements:(1/0)");
       scanf("%d",&ch);
   }
   while(ch==1);
}
```

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]

Comment: Hint: Learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: The massive use of global variables (`head`, `ch`, `start` and `ptr`) makes me think you should rethink your program from the ground up.

Comment: I just made a [mcve] by writing some minimal code so I could test the `create` function and it works fine. The problem is elsewhere in the code you didn't show us.

Comment: here is the link to the complete code->>>>  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B72VhP-JuqyKM1BGQnZBYk1rUzg

Comment: here is the links for the screenshot with the error.  ->> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B72VhP-JuqyKdFY3VTNwLXc2UUU/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B72VhP-JuqyKQ2hFWUw1dzZxM2M/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B72VhP-JuqyKMmpGSW1VdHhPNnc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observe from your code that you are using ptr as a pointer to the last node of the linked list as shown in the following lines of create() function :-

```
if (start==NULL)
    start = ptr = head;
else
{
    ptr->next=head;
    ptr=head;
}
```

While in the display function, you are again initialiing

```
ptr = start;
```

and then traversing to the end of the loop, where ptr becomes null as in the following lines :-

```
while(ptr!=NULL)
{
    printf("%d->",ptr->num);
    ptr=ptr->next;
}
```

(Similarly in delast() and delany() functions, you are doing the following operation :-

```
free(ptr);
```

which will again result in making ptr = null, thus resulting in **segmentation fault**. )

Thus, when you create list for 1st time, code works fine, because the value of ptr is preserved, however, once you display the list, or delete any element and then again go back to create the list(Menu option 1), the value of ptr becomes null, so,

```
ptr->next = head;
```

results in **Segmentation Fault**.

So, one possible solution is to use a new pointer say *end instead of *ptr in the create() function, and never make the value of end = null; as shown below :-

```
void create()
{
 do{
    printf("Enter the num:");
    head=(NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    scanf("%d",&head->num);
    head->next=NULL;
    if(start==NULL)
        start=end=head;
    else
    {
        end->next=head;
        end=head;
    }
    printf("Do you want to enter more elements:(1/0)");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
}
 while(ch==1);
}
```

Or, you when creating the list, you can traverse to the end of the list to add new element, instead of directly using the end pointer (so, no need of saving the extra end pointer).

```
void create()
{
 do{
    printf("Enter the num:");
    head=(NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    scanf("%d",&head->num);
    head->next=NULL;
    if(start == NULL)
        start = head;
    else
    {
        ptr = start;
        while (ptr->next != NULL){
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next = head;
    }        
    printf("Do you want to enter more elements:(1/0)");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
}
 while(ch==1);
}
```